# How to create a multi-dimensional container by another different type multi-dimensional container?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have a 2D container whose first dimension is **deque**, and second dimensional is **vector**.

How to translate it to the new container whose first and
second dimensional is the same **vector** ?

```
vector<deque<int>>   v1;
vector<vector<int>>  v2{v1}; //error
vector<vector<int>>  v3(v1.begin(),v1.end()); // error 

/* the different type deque<int> couldn't be used for vector<int> constructer. */
```

I know that I can copy the bottom element step by step  manually. Is there any algorithm can finish it at once?

Comment: Don't just say "error", include the exact error text. This helps narrow down the problem.

Comment: Please, provide the error message you're getting.

Comment: The complier error message is too long to read ( >15 lines ) , and I add the comment to explain the reason of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v3;
v3.reserve(v1.size());

std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v3), [](const auto& d)
    {
    return std::vector<int>(d.begin(), d.end());
    });
```

Comment: Not that it makes a big difference in specific case, but a cleaner implementation would be to call `reserve()` on v3 and use a `std::back_inserter` instead of pre-sizing `v3`.

Comment: @Frank Yes, that's an option, but what's cleaner about it? Neither here nor there in terms of efficiency, and it requires an extra line of code.

Comment: It changes a default construction followed by a move assignment (and implicitly a destruction of the default-constructed object) into single move-construction N times. It's a good habit to get into in general, and for large enough vectors, it could actually have a small impact on efficiency as you need to do multiple passes over the same memory range, potentially thrashing the cache.

Comment: OK, I agree. :)

Comment: @acraig5075 , thank your clever solution . That's I want. 
@Frank , It's a pity that there is no method to construct a vector object and use `reserve()` in a 
 statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand, that C++ can't cast deque to vector directly. In third line in your example, there was hidden loop, similar to this(but it use iterators and so on)

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
    v3[i] = v1[i]; // here we try to cast deque to vector
```

So there is 3 ways, how to accomplish your goal:

1. Use some function from algorithm library like [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)(example in acraig5075 answer)
2. Iterate yourself

```
v3.reserve(v1.size());
for(size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
    v3.emplace_back(v1[i].begin(), v1[i].end());
```

3. Directly say compiler how to cast one class to another, but I don't know if there is such a possibility for standard classes (but for classes of own implementation such is available)

Comment: Same comment as with @acraig5075's solution: don't resize a vector if you are initializing it. `reserve()` and `push_back()` instead (or even `emplace_back()` in this specific case).

Comment: In our case this should not matter(empty constructor doesn't call allocation in most implementation, but this is not standart), but you are right, I think it's a good practice to use ```reserve```+```push_back``` instead of ```resize```+```operator[]``` in general case

Comment: The constructor still needs to assign at least a size and capacity (and probably a null pointer too) to each vector. And on assignment, that needs to be checked to see if a delete is necessary. On large enough vectors of vectors, this adds up.